# Como generar un mensaje después de ejecutar una sentencia SQL en AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Estoy generando un método que permite realizar un UPDATE en mi base de datos a través de ajax. Básicamente estoy mandando un json al formulario php. Al parecer se ejecuta normalmente, pero en el función Succes() emito un mensaje de alerta para indicar al usuario que se ha ejecutado con éxito la sentencia, pero este no me esta devolviendo nada.

Adjunto el ejemplo en cuestión.

```js
function restablecerPassword() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "lib/gestion/contrasenia/enviar_contrasenia.php",
      method: "post",
      data: {
        "correo": "asd@gmail.com",
        "clave": "asd"
      },
      success: function(data) {
        alert("Respuesta: "+data);
      },
      error: function() {
        alert('Not OKay');
      }
    });
}
```

El código PHP es el siguiente

```
<?php

$correo = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'correo');
$password = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'clave');

require_once '../../../files/clases/Conexion.php';

$respuesta = '{"password":[]}';
$conexion = Conexion::establecer();
    if(!$conexion->connect_error){
        $sql = "UPDATE Usuario SET contrasenia = '".$password."' WHERE correo = '".$correo."';";
        if($conexion->query($sql))$respuesta = '{"password":'.json_encode($password).'}';
        else echo $conexion->error;
        $conexion->close();
}
echo $respuesta;

?>
```

Aguardo comentarios

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

En primer lugar, agregaría dataType: "json" entre las opciones de la función ajax.

En el archivo php, te sugiero que utilices una array común y luego lo pases a json_encode.

En tercer lugar, al añadir data al texto de la alerta le están adjuntando todo el objeto devuelto.